# <hr> tag invisible in ios & android devices browsers

Tags: android, html, ios, css

---

Tag invisible in IOS & Android devices browsers
code is as follows

html

```
<hr class="separator_border">
```

css

```
.separator_border {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 3px none;
}
```

The above code is working when we changed the user agent in Desktop.
In actual android & IOS devices browser it's not showing the hr.

But in few Android devices the "hr" tag is visible it's not happening in all the devices.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem should be the "border: 3px none;" you make 3px of nothing.
Try "border: 3px solid #000;" instead.