# <hr> not showing up on mobile e-mail clients

Tags: ios, css, email, responsive-design

I'm experiencing issues with `<hr>`only showing up as a black dot on mobile e-mail clients. Here's what I'm using in my CSS:

```
 hr {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #333333;
  height: 1px;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100% !important;
  }
```

I've seen a few different suggestions on this site such as:
 [<hr> tag invisible in ios & android devices browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301267/hr-tag-invisible-in-ios-android-devices-browsers)

or

[<hr> not displaying at all on IOS Safari and regular android browser.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284957/hr-not-displaying-at-all-on-ios-safari-and-regular-android-browser)

But none of the solutions seem to be working for me.

Any help is great appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What email clients are you using? Can you show us the e-mail? Sometimes you can just change it for a bottom border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue can be solved if you remove these lines

```
color: #333333;
background-color: #333333;
height: 1px;
border: none;
```

And add the following line

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
```